# Symfony assetic doesn't work properly

Tags: symfony, bower, assetic

I have problem with assetic in symfony. Stylesheet part does not work at all in dev environment (css styles are not applied to the document) and in production environment everything is ok except resources are not linked correctly for fontawesome

I am using bower and my .bowerrc file:

```
{
    "directory": "src/Acme/AdminBundle/Resources/public/3rdparty"
}
```

My config.app file:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    bundles:        ["AcmeAdminBundle"]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/../bin/yuicompressor.jar"
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/../bin/yuicompressor.jar"
```

and finally the layout.html.twig

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite,yui_css' output='css/3rdparty.css'
    '@AcmeAdminBundle/Resources/public/3rdparty/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    '@AcmeAdminBundle/Resources/public/3rdparty/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css'
%}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

[output](http://oi57.tinypic.com/sbms2a.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that causes the `cssrewrite` filter to fail when using the **@AcmeFooBundle** syntax for CSS Stylesheets<sup>[document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter)</sup>.

In other words, you can't use **@AcmeFooBundle** and `cssrewrite` filter together.